# how to track sendtoaddress / sendmany in case of network failure

Tags: bitcoin-cli

Suppose you call sendmany or sendtoaddress on bitcoind RPC.

Suppose the transaction is created and send to the network, but RPC time out and sender process unable to read the txid.

Suppose there are several send to same address with same btc amount.

How this can be tracked programically?

I know you can pass comment to each send but I am unsure how I can collect it programically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do gettransaction, comment is available in the JSON. One need to set up callback for transaction and watch for his own comment.

I will update the answer with JSON dumps once I do enough testing.

Answer (score 1):

In the event that `bitcoind` completes a transaction, but the RPC response is lost, the transaction details will still remain available. The wallet and transaction database is updated directly by `bitcoind`, and will be updated regardless of the RPC state.

Comment: Sure. But how I can access it?

Comment: Just use the list transaction/wallet history RPC commands in a new RPC connection, the txs will be in your history. If there are N txs for the same amount to the same address simultaneously, does it really matter which txid is assigned to which tx? They are all fungible